Drupal 8 taxonomy block
I have following taxonomy block
block--views-block--related-theme-themes-sitemap.html.twig
I need to get all the taxonomy items in this block and then style them separately.
Following code I was trying but not getting results,
`{%
set classes = [
'block',
'block-'~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
'block-'~ plugin_id|clean_class,
'clearfix',
]
%}

{{ title_prefix }}
{% if label %}
<h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('block-title') }}\>{{ label }}</h2>
{% endif %}
{{ title_suffix }}

  <ul>
  {% for item in content %}
    <li> {{title}} </li>
  {% endfor %}

  </ul>`

Any ideas?

First create a view by navigating to {domain}/admin/structure/views/add

In the create view page >> VIEW SETTINGS >> select taxonomy terms >> select type
Check on create a block >> select BLOCK DISPLAY SETTINGS based on your needs.
Click on save and edit.
Now customise based on your requirement.

For more information refer below links:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/create-a-simple-block-view

Hi Viswanath, I have already created the view and view block, the issue is I need to customize it using Twig template, where I am having issues, as explained above question.

what is the template name and view name. you should use proper template for the block and alter the block contents using any hooks available.
